# Replace point decimal separator with comma

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I regularly get a big amount of data, to be processed. Some columns contain numbers, where the decimal separator is a point.

In my country the decimal separator is a comma, so these numbers are imported as text. In my process, the first job is to convert them into numbers.

I change the point to comma, and then multiply it with 1, the result is a number.

I just realized, in some cases the decimal separator disappears.

[image]

```
Sub Sort_intezkedes()
    Dim Cel As Worksheet
    Set Cel = Sheets("Munka1")
    Cel.Select

    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = 0

    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 1 To 10
        Cel.Range("B2").Offset(LastRow).Value = Replace(Cel.Range("A1").Offset(j).Value, ".", ",") 
        Cel.Range("C2").Offset(LastRow).Value = Cel.Range("B2").Offset(LastRow).Value * 1
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: You could use `TextToColumn` for this. Do you want the values in column C or can they stay in column A?

Comment: The `Replace` function is not the culprit here, it's the cell value affectation that is bugged. `Range("B2").Value = "1,234567"` will give the same result of `1 234 567` (with format changed automatically to "Number"). If you force the format to Text before you will have the expected result.

Comment: intersting value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, you could tackle this using `TextToColumns`, try:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim lr As Long

With Sheet1 'Change accordingly
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & lr)
    rng.TextToColumns .Range("A2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1), DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=",", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End With

End Sub
```

The above would paste results in `.Range("A2")`, so change to your liking.

***Sidenote:*** You are using a variable name `Cel` for the `Worksheet` object. That's confusing =)

Comment: I need the numbers in a new position, but I can copy in the first step, and convert in the second.
You are right, the `Cel` can be confusing. In my language it means target, which is useful for me in the full process, but meaningless here.

Comment: @barathg, no need to copy, just change the `Destination` parameter (the first one) to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Your undertaking is scary because of its potential to convert perfectly good data into rubbish. The code below will replace commas with periods only if the cell's NumberFormat = "General". Right-click on a cell, select *Format Cells*. "General" is the first item on the *Number* tab. It's the default format of all virgin cells on Excel sheets, and it's the "General" format that lets Excel guess whether you entered a number or text. This feature enables you to exclude columns or cells in your worksheet from the devastation of my code simply by applying another format, e.g. 0.000000 or "Text".

```
Sub TextToNumber()

    Const FirstRow As Long = 2          ' set as required
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim C As Long                       ' selected column
    Dim Rl As Long                      ' last row
    Dim R As Long
    Dim Tmp As Variant

    C = Selection.Column
    Rl = Cells(Rows.Count, C).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(FirstRow, C), Cells(Rl, C))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For R = FirstRow To Rl
        With Cells(R, C)
            If .NumberFormat = "General" Then
                Tmp = .Value
                Tmp = Replace(Tmp, ",", ".")
                .Value = Tmp
            End If
        End With
    Next R
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

My code performs on the column you select before you run it. Select any single cell (no need to select the entire column). If you select several columns only the first one will be treated. Commas will be replaced with periods from the first row you can set in the code to the end of the column which the macro finds on its own.